# Two main classes on netbeans project

Tags: java, email, netbeans, jar

So I'm working on a large project and I want to implement a function to send emails automatically with reports at let's say 12:00 am.
I have successfully created the aforementioned routine, which reads a file with a list of mails and sends them (I have the mails saved under my root directory, because other part of my program allows users to edit the list of mails themselves), as I need to send the mails at 12:00 am regardless my application is running or not, I created a main() in order to schedule the routine in my Windows OS.

My question is, how can I run this routine (which uses the main application classes to generate the report) when I already have another main() in the same project (which is the user interface) and not creating conflicts? If I run the project as a whole on netbeans it runs my gui as expected, same from command prompt, but I can't run my mail routine from the console (on netbeans it runs fine with Run File...)

Comment: I believe you could use the command line arguments for that, ie. the `String[] args` parameter in the main method. Then you only need one `main` method, and change the arguments based on where you are running from . See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) also.

Comment: With what command do you run your program in the commandline?

Comment: @JonasCz How would that call to a main method look like? Because in order to send `args[]` I suppose I need to use the command line to execute my .jar right? Because my users would not want to access my .jar through command prompt...

Comment: @AndreasSinz I called `MyDirectory > java MyJar`

Comment: Yes, to use `args[]`, you need to run from command line.

Answer (score 1):

In order to tell java which Main-Method to run,
you can use the following syntax:

```
java -cp YourJar.jar com.package.to.your.YourMainClass
```

Comment: You can have as many entry points (`public static void main(String[] args)`) as you want, and you can, as Andreas Sinz points out, just specify which MainClass you want to run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I get a `Error: Could not find or load a main class JarFILENAME`